# expected steps to reach to the end of a line

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

This is a question in Sheldon Ross's *Stochastic Processes*.

> A particle moves along the following graph so that at each step it is equally likely to move to any of its neighbors.
> [image]
> Starting at $0$ show that the expected number of steps it takes to reach $n$ is $n^2$.
>
> (*Hint*. Let $T_i$ denote the number of steps it takes to go from vertex $i-1$ to vertex $i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$. Determine $E[T_i]$ recursively, first for $i=1$, then $i=2$, and so on.)

Here is the answer in Ross' book.

> $E[T_1]=1$.
>
> For $i>1$,
> $$E[T_i]=1+1/2(E[\text{time to go from}\ i-2\ \text{to}\ i]=1+1/2(E[T_{i_1}]+E[T_i])$$
> and so,
> $$E[T_i]=2+E[T_{i-1}],\quad i>1.$$

I don't understand how this recurrence relation is obtained. What does the $\frac{1}{2}$ in the second term represent? If it means the probability $\frac{1}{2}$, shouldn't the first term $1$ be replaced by $\frac{1}{2}$ also?

Answer (score 1):

No matter whether you go forward or backwards, you will make at least 1 move, that's why there's a 1 in front. Then, on the 50% chance that you move backwards, you're 2 nodes away from your goal, so you have to add the expected moves to go from i-2 to i-1 (E[T_{i-1}]) and the expected moves to go from i-1 to i (E[T_i]).

This equation is concise, but it's not intuitive.

Another way to think of it is to split the equation into the half chance you move forward and the half chance you move backwards:
E[T_i] = (1/2)(1) + (1/2)(1 + E[T_{i-1}] + E[T_i]).

In both cases, you make at least 1 move.